# WordPress 301 redirects for 300 links to redirect in .htaccess?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

my question is would it slow my website? I am migrating from a non WP CMS to a WP CMS which means there are quite a fair deal of links to redirect due to a different URL structure. I plan on doing my redirects as follows: `Redirect 301 /old-page/ http://www.newwebsite.com/new-page/`

I include that line below the `# END WordPress`.
So basically there will be roughly 300 lines of `Redirect 301 ...` in my .htaccess file.

Would this really slow down my site? I have to include all the 300 redirects and I'm using WP.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking to redirect your entire site to a new domain or only migrating from a static site to CMS? What's your current permalink structure? Why are you planning to redirect it, you can customize your permalink structure in wordpress to fit your existing structure.

Comment: The domains remain the same. The previous site was created by silverstripe CMS. I did not create the previous website it was created by a previous developer. So I created the new website and need to redirect the URl as they don't follow the same structure.

Comment: What's the current permalink structure? Wordpress is so flexible when it comes to setting up the permalink structure... You can match it with the existing one by using either the default permalink feature under settings or by using the power of .htaccess. This technique will surely help you a lot. For example you don't need to get your current site re-indexed in major search engines. You don't need to perform multiple redirects on your existing site.

Comment: If I did decide to include the redirects in .htaccess would it slow down my site?

Comment: for example /cars/four-wheels/honda4x4/low-price would now be /cheap-cars/4x4/honda/low-budget

Comment: Not much, it all depends upon the performance of your server since it renders through the server's resources.  But this will surely increase the server load, in addition to it, use wp-cache to minimize the server load.

Comment: if it's a need to redirect the old pages, then the only preferable way is to use .htaccess